# Ansible-container example build failed

Tags: ansible, ansible-container

I'm trying to build the very default example (ansible.django-template) with Ansible container and with `ansible-container build` I end up with

```
Building Docker Engine context...
Starting Docker build of Ansible Container Conductor image (please be patient)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/conductor", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ansible-container', 'console_scripts', 'conductor')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 560, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2648, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2302, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2308, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/_ansible/container/cli.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .utils.visibility import getLogger
  File "/_ansible/container/utils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ansible.vars import VariableManager
ImportError: cannot import name VariableManager
Conductor terminated. Cleaning up.  command_rc=1 conductor_id=5d96fc65006af97aa4deb3d0adaae44104f82fd591d7f9199449b1b9efaa2c6d save_container=False
ERROR   Conductor exited with status 1
```

Ansible 2.3.0.0 from pip + ansible-container 0.9.0.0[docker]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use the very latest version of ansible-container which can only be installed "from source" as detailed here:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/installation.html

There have been lots of changes since the version which you can download with pip.